# Specified part does not exist in the package

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have the following code:

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
{
    ....
}
```

Where string filename is a valid path to a docx file.

But calling Open causes the following InvalidOperationException: `Specified part does not exist in the package.`

**Edit:** I assume the problem is due to the docx file I'm trying to open being invalid so I'll post the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
    <w:body xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:p w:rsidRPr="005501CD" w:rsidR="00217D87" w:rsidP="005501CD" w:rsidRDefault="005501CD">
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Hello </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:noProof />
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>John</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:noProof />
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Smith</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>,</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0" />
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidRPr="005501CD" w:rsidR="00217D87">
            <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
            <w:cols w:space="708" />
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Other docx files open fine, but I suspect a bug in my mail merge code is causing an invalid docx file to be generated.

Comment: are you using the full path  to your file?

Comment: @Jane Doe yes I'm using the full path.

Comment: @Andy: Does your docx file contain references to external files?

Comment: @Hans - no but I suspect my manipulation of the docx file has made it invalid.  I'll edit the question to include the xml.

Comment: Download the OpenXML Productivity Tool and see if the document is encountering any validation errors.

Comment: Could you post your mail merge code?

Comment: @skynorth - thanks I didn't know the tool existed - it looks useful, but I get the same error when trying to open my docx file in that too!

Comment: @Hans I was trying out some code for mail merge that I found online here: http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/08/05/463.aspx?PageIndex=14

Comment: I've submitted a pull request with a better error message to the Open XML github repo at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/pull/29

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out the problem was due to a missing xml file.  In case anyone else runs into similar problems, check the following:

1. rename yourfile.docx to yourfile.zip
2. extract the zip file and look in the file called `[Content-Types].xml`
3. check that all the xml files listed in `[Content-Types].xml` exist in your zip file.

In my case I had the following line in my `[Content-Types].xml` file:

```
<Override PartName="/word/recipientData.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-word.mailMergeRecipientData+xml"/>
```

But I was missing the `recipientData.xml` file from the word directory.

Comment: What is then the easiest approach from here? Do you put a mock file in its place or do you remove traces of its existence?

Comment: From memory,  I think I removed the reference to the file,  but can't remember for certain.

Comment: Followed your answer, but it still didn't fix my problem :(  Thanks for the info, though.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I added a .png media without adding the following row in `[Content_Types].xml`:

```
<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
```

Comment: My problem was slightly different, but your comment inspired me - the `[Content_Types].xml` I was using had `<Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>` - but the images I programatically inserted into the DocX file had a '.jpg' , not '.jpeg' extension. When I changed the extension from .jpg to .jpeg the file finally loaded fine !

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for this @neclepsio . Editing DocX files is really a dark art, but this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

In the XML you posted above you are missing the `</w:document>` closing tag.  This will cause the document part to not be found and is probably why you are seeing that error message.

Comment: +1 for spotting that - although that's not the actual problem - it turns out I'd just failed to copy and paste in the whole xml file!

Comment: bizarrely when I click edit on my initial post, `</w:document>` is there, but it doesn't get displayed!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was an image referenced in `word/_rels/document.xml.rels` that was not present in the zip.

Including the images that were referenced fixed the problem.