# OpenXml SpreadsheetDocument.Open(...) get exception - The main part is missing

Tags: c#, .net, excel, xls, openxml-sdk

I have an xlsx doc with headers and it is located in my project path.
I want to insert data using OpenXML but I get an exception while opening the file:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(MyxlsFileName, true))
{
    // ...
}
```

The exception:

> "The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing"

What is the meaning of the exception and what is wrong?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot open **XLS** files with OpenXml. You must save your Excel file as an **XLSX** file using Microsoft Excel 2007 or newer. (Assuming you are using the correct file extension here...)

Files with XLS extension are in a proprietary binary format which cannot be processed with OpenXML.

So you have two options:

1. Convert your XLS files to XLSX manually before processing them.
2. Find a library or API to process XLS files.

Comment: I tried with xlsx file and I get the same exception.

Comment: Make sure you save your file with the correct file type. You must use Excel 2007 or 2010 and in the Save dialog where it says: "Save as type:" choose "Excel Workbook" and NOT "Excel 97-2003 Workbook".

Comment: That exactly what I did.

Comment: Make sure the file is not open in Excel whiule you try to read it, also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212374/specified-part-does-not-exist-in-the-package

Comment: The file is close during run time. The link above is about xml file I am using xlsx file that I created myself.

Comment: Good.I created file by code and  the exception didn't arise again.
Thank you.

Comment: @helb i have a docx file and yet i get this error. Can you explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 6):

While this might be very obvious, it happened to me: Another situation that might trigger the excact same error is when you get the name of the file wrong.
So check that you really have the path right, for me I ended up with a newly created file (with the wrong spelling) but still got the very same error.

Answer (score -3):

try using SpreadsheetDocument.Create

instead of "Open"